# NSArray from array in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary loaded from a remote PList.
It contains an array of dictionaries:

```
(
    {
    id = "1234";
    count = "45";
    },
    {
    id = "244";
    count = "89";
    },
    {
    id = "9909";
    count = "123";
    }
)
```

How do I get this into an NSArray? I don't want separate arrays for each key.
I just want an NSArray of NSDictionary.

There is probably a simple answer, but this has been bugging me.

Thanks

Comment: what is this "    It contains an array of dictionaries:    I just want an NSArray of NSDictionary".

Comment: What you have there is an array of name-values pair.  Dictionaries are really good at holding onto and manipulating name-value pairs, so maybe that's what you want to do -- import the list of NVPairs into a dictionary?  If not, then I think you might want to better explain what you mean by an "NSArray of NSDictionary".

Comment: The PList looks like this:

`<array>
    <dict>
        <key>id</key>
 <real>1234</real>
 <key>count</key>
 <real>123</real>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>id</key>
 <real>223</real>
 <key>count</key>
 <real>2</real>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>id</key>
 <real>777</real>
 <key>count</key>
 <real>15523</real>
    </dict>
</array>`

The root element of the created NSDictionary is an array without a key.
I'm trying to figure out how to get this array into a NSArray.

If I added this array with a key, I could just use objectForKey to get the NSArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have a dictionary containing the array. Whatever the key for the array is, just ask do `[dictionary objectForKey:theKey]`, and you'll have the array.

EDIT: From your comments, it sounds like you just have an NSArray which is *not* in an NSDictionary at all. If so, you already have what you are looking for.

Comment: There is no key for the array. That's the problem. :s

Comment: @Ty Kroll: Then you don't have "a NSDictionary loaded from a remote PList … [that] contains an array of dictionaries". Everything that's in a dictionary has a key. If there's no key for it, it's not in a dictionary. So the question is: What do you *actually* have, if not a dictionary?

Comment: That is odd indeed.

I use NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:mutabilityOption:format:error to load NSData from a remote PList with the format above.

Perhaps it should have saved me from myself. I definitely have an array of dictionaries. Printing my resulting NSDictionary shows something similar to what I showed in my first post.

Comment: @Ty Kroll: Have you tried asking the object what its class is? It sounds like you just have an NSArray.

Comment: Whoah! __NSCFArray. Crazy. 

Just casting it into NSArray* did the trick.

Curious why I could get away with passing it around as a NSDictionary* when it was really a NSArray*.

Comment: The docs for NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData explain it:

"A property list object corresponding to the representation in data. If data is not in a supported format, returns nil."

My fault for assuming it returned NSDictionary.

Comment: @Ty Kroll: You could pass it around as an `NSDictionary*` because the compiler had no way of knowing it didn't actually point to an NSDictionary — that's how dynamic typing works. All object pointer types are basically equivalent to `id`. When you assign an `id` value to a statically typed pointer, the compiler just trusts that you're telling it the truth. The compiler uses static types for type checking, but at runtime they all blend together into a generic idea of "pointer to an object."

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
NSArray *dicts = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data
                                                           options:0
                                                            format:NSPropertyListOpenStepFormat
                                                             error:NULL];
```

Note that this is a deprecated plist format (XML or binary format is now preferred).

Comment: Is this only available in >= XCode 4?

Comment: No, it's been available for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

have u tried [dictionary objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0]. try iterating over objectAtIndex in the outer loop.

all the best.